# Temperature through a dual stage compressor

Tags: thermodynamics

A   two-stage   axial-flow  compressor  operates    with    a   100kg/s inflow  of  air at  298K,   1bar    and an  overall pressure    ratio   of  25.

Both    stages  have    a   pressure    ratio   of  5   and
isentropic  efficiency  of  0.88.   Neglect changes in  kinetic energy  and potential
energy

a) Sketch process on T-S diagram - done no problem

b) Find the power   required    if  the compression were    reversible. - done with the correct answer of -45,400KW

c) Find the compressor  outlet  temperature - The the answer in the back of the textbook says the correct answer is 825K. But I am unable to get this. I tried using the efficiency of the compressor and the ideal gas equation but neither worked. Does anyone have any ideas? - My working is attached below. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Isn't the trick to do p2/p1 with p3/p2 so you use p3/p1 as the overall pressure change? Check the textbooks - this is covered.

Comment: But P3/P1 =  ρ3 * T3 /  ρ1 * T1  you can work out the density  ρ1 but the density  ρ3 cannot be calculated.

Comment: this is possible - it was in an exam question that I sat many years ago... I had forgotten how to get through it during the exam though. So it is covered in the textbooks.